# Using erase() in a while loop and segfault C++

Tags: c++, string, parsing, getline

Okay, so I'm having a bit of a problem here. The thing is this code works on a friend's computer but I'm getting segmentation faults when I try to run it.

I am reading a file looking like so:

```
word 2 wor ord
anotherword 7 ano oth the her erw wor ord
...
```

And I want to parse every word of the file. The first two words (e.g. word and 2) are to be erased but saving the first one in another variable in the process.

I've looked around a bit on accomplishing this, and I've come up with this half-assed piece of code that seems to work on my friends' computer but not mine.

```
Dictionary::Dictionary() {
    ifstream ip;
    ip.open("words.txt", ifstream::in);
    string input;
    string buf;
    vector<string> tokens; // Holds words
    while(getline(ip, input)){
        if(input != " ") {
            stringstream ss(input);
            while(ss >> buf) {
                tokens.push_back(buf);
        }
        string werd = tokens.at(0);
        tokens.erase(tokens.begin()); // Remove the word from the vector
        tokens.erase(tokens.begin()); // Remove the number indicating trigrams
        Word curr(werd, tokens); 
        words[werd.length()].push_back(curr); // Put the word at the vector with word length i.
        tokens.clear();
    }
}
ip.close();
}
```

What's the best of of parsing this kind of structure in a file and removing the first two elements but saving the others? As you can see, I'm making a Word object that contains a string and a vector for later use.

Regards

EDIT; It seems to add the first line fine, but on removal of the second element, it crashes with a segmentation fault error.

EDIT; words.txt contain this:

```
addict 4 add ddi dic ict 
sinister 6 ini ist nis sin ste ter 
test 2 est tes 
cplusplus 7 cpl lus lus plu plu spl usp
```

Without leading blank spaces or ending blanks. Not that it reads all the way anyway.

Word.cc:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "word.h"

using namespace std;

Word::Word(const string& w, const vector<string>& t) : word(w), trigrams(t) {}

string Word::get_word() const {
    return word;
}

unsigned int Word::get_matches(const vector<string>& t) const {
    vector<string> sharedTrigrams;
    set_intersection(t.begin(),t.end(), trigrams.begin(), trigrams.end(), back_inserter(sharedTrigrams));
    return sharedTrigrams.size();
}
```

Comment: Reading a blank line from the beginning of the file easily messes up the program. Instead of pushing lots of things onto a vector and then erasing two of them, I'd recommend just not pushing them in the first place.

Comment: @chris there you go again, trying to do things the easy way =P (uptick)

Comment: type/size of words array?

Comment: `The thing is this code works on a friend's computer but I'm getting segmentation faults when I try to run it.`  Well, it isn't your computer that is the problem.  Welcome to the world of "undefined behavior".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Thank goodness, you caught me in the checkout line at the computer store.

Comment: @chris how would you go about doing this?

Comment: @Ludo6431 I'm assuming you mean the words read by ifstream, its large. Why?

Comment: @enrm, Since you know there are two useless leading tokens, a constant with the value 2, and a function called something like `discardLeadingTokens` that just reads into a string twice and discards it.

Comment: I reformatted the code, so you can see the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ifstream ip;
ip.open("words.txt", ifstream::in);
string input;
while(getline(ip, input)){
   istringstream iss(input);
   string str;
   unsigned int count = 0;
   if(iss >> str >> count) {
     vector<string> tokens { istream_iterator<string>(iss),    istream_iterator<string>() }; // Holds words
  if(tokens.size() == count) 
        words[str.length()].emplace_back(str, tokens);
  }      
}
ip.close();
```

This is what I used to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is error in the number of closing `}`s in your posted code. If you indent them properly, you will see that your code is:

```
while(getline(ip, input))
{
   if(input != " ") 
   {
      stringstream ss(input);
      while(ss >> buf) {
         tokens.push_back(buf);
      }
   }
   string werd = tokens.at(0);
   tokens.erase(tokens.begin());
   tokens.erase(tokens.begin());
   Word curr(werd, tokens); 
   words[werd.length()].push_back(curr);
   tokens.clear();
}
}
```

Assuming that is a small typo in posting, the other problem is that `tokens` is an empty list when `input == " "` yet you continue to use `tokens` as though it has 2 or more items in it.

You can fix that by moving everything inside the `if` statement.

```
while(getline(ip, input))
{
   if(input != " ") 
   {
      stringstream ss(input);
      while(ss >> buf) {
         tokens.push_back(buf);
      }

      string werd = tokens.at(0);
      tokens.erase(tokens.begin());
      tokens.erase(tokens.begin());
      Word curr(werd, tokens); 
      words[werd.length()].push_back(curr);
      tokens.clear();
   }
}
```

I would add further checks to make it more robust.

```
while(getline(ip, input))
{
   if(input != " ") 
   {
      stringstream ss(input);
      while(ss >> buf) {
         tokens.push_back(buf);
      }

      string werd;

      if ( !tokens.empty() )
      {
         werd = tokens.at(0);
         tokens.erase(tokens.begin());
      }

      if ( !tokens.empty() )
      {
         tokens.erase(tokens.begin());
      }

      Word curr(werd, tokens); 
      words[werd.length()].push_back(curr);
      tokens.clear();
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that last brace was something I missed when I pasted the code here and removed a print statement for my own error checking purposes. Its not there in the real code.
The code still doesn't work even though the braces are correct.

I tried adding a
    vector<string> exportTokens = vector<string>(tokens.begin()+2, tokens.end()); 

And removing the erase() calls but still fails..

Comment: Since your posted code does not have an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's difficult to see what other problems could be there in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the initialization of the variable "words" in your code.  Just looking at it, I am guessing you are initializing "words" to be a fixed-length array of vectors, but then read a word that is off the end of the array.  Bang, you're dead.  Add a check to "werd.length()" to ensure it is strictly less than the length of "words".

Comment: You are correct, however, the words array is 25 slots, and none of the words are this big in my file.

Comment: @enrm - `and none of the words are this big in my file.`  If I had a dollar for all of the posters that claim "I am doing x", but are really not doing "x", I would be a rich man.  Please *ensure* that the array isn't being breached by a large word by writing the code to check for this condition.